# Where do print statements in a published iOS app go?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I obviously know where they go when I'm testing the app in Xcode. 
But if I were to release an app to the App Store that contained print statements, would they be logged in the user's device somewhere or would they just be ignored?

Comment: they are logged to stdout/stderr as usual. If you connect your device to something that can read that (e.g. using syslogd), they will be visible.

Answer (score 3):

They get logged to the user's device in a way that they're accessible from Xcode. Apple explains the behavior [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is an internal "console" for each app. They are not necessarily logged anywhere except in this internal console. When you test your app in Xcode, it connects to this internal console and copies any print statements from the the device to Xcode for developers to see.